# How Can I execute a query When Time= this

Tags: php, mysql

i want to run a query at a specific time

For Example if Time is 5:10:25 execute this query

it tried with following code

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Calcutta");
$time=date("h:i:s");
if ($time=='04:10:00')
{
$sql="insert into bsechartsdata (TickerPlantCode,DateTime,OpenPrice,HighPrice,LowPrice,ClosePrice) select DISTINCT TickerPlantCode,DateTime,OpenPrice,HighPrice,LowPrice,ClosePrice from bsepricequotes_latest";
$query=mysql_query($sql);
}
```

but the query is not executing 
where am doing wrong ?

Comment: check the `mysql_error` for it first ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it not better to use a cron job for this?
http://www.pantz.org/software/cron/croninfo.html

If you don't have support for this on your "host", then you can make a database with jobs that needs to get done. If the time is passed that is in the database, then then you do the task.

Answer (score 1):

If you are integrating that type of code in a web application you need a person (and just one) to make a request exactly when you want so it doesn't sound 
like a good idea. Research cron jobs under Linux (or scheduled tasks if you are using a windows server)

Answer (score 0):

Add the current timestamp/time to here:

```
$time=date("h:i:s", time());
```

Comment: @mishu: ahh, ok. Didn't read until the end of the manual description.

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better to use a [cron job](http://www.cronjob.com/) to run a script which will execute that query.

An if statement like yours would require that someone be running that specific page at that exact second.

Answer (score 0):

PHP code must be triggered by some sort of source.
If a user hits your web server at *precisely* 04:10:00, the query will execute.
But you can't expect PHP to take the instructions you've given it and remember to perform a procedure at a specified time like that.

In short - You need to set up a [Cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a query queue, a table with some kind of structure:

- execute_after DATETIME
- my_query TEXT

Then just create a script that runs every minute (or multiple times per minute: there are tricks for that). Then you just insert the query you want to run in the queue and your cronjob will execute it when it should!

Answer (score 0):

Do you need leading zero or not?

```
$time=date("H:i:s");
```

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron + You have need to check current time with your time on every cron run, 
whenever current time is less then your time then you have to execute your query.

and you have need to set flag for this (if flag is not set then only run query)